# Javascript execution in AwesomiumSharp

Tags: javascript, awesomium

I integrate Awesomium into a client app. Then I let Awesomium load customized local html file, where I used my Javascript code. Very simple, this code will open a new URL when I click the button.

The code is like this:

```
<input type="button" value="click to open" onclick='loadUrl()' />

function loadUrl()
{
    window.open("http://www.google.com", "_self");
}
```

but nothing happened when I click the button. I also test this code in Chrome Browser, it works fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the reserved word, "_self", for the target window name. Use something else (or "_blank").